# org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:7055

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mozilla

Selenium Webdriver(2.53) and java (jdk 7). Mozilla Firefox ESR (45.2.0) crashes as soon as page opens gives error message:

Getting error

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
System info: host: 'ADMINIB-8GSESH3', ip: '9.84.222.238', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_71'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver


Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=45.2.0}]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:665)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:701)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.quit(RemoteWebDriver.java:526)
    at com.refread.fed.search.utils.WebDriverUtils.close(WebDriverUtils.java:711)
    at com.refread.fed.search.connector.headless.IEEE.searchResults(IEEE.java:106)
    at com.refread.fed.search.connector.headless.IEEE.main(IEEE.java:147)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:7055 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:151)
```

Comment: verify if some service is listening in port 7055 of localhost

Comment: how to check that?

Comment: in windows you can open `Resource Monitor`, open network tab, look for the last section named `Listening Ports` (tip: sort by port number).. See if there is an entry in the list for port 7055, make sure `Address` field value of the entry is either `IPv4 unspecified` or `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.. if such an entry doesn't exist for the port the service which you are trying to connect isn't running

Comment: No port is not there

Comment: What to do. Please suggest.

Comment: I think there is compatible issue. Selenium version is 2.53.0 and firefox 45.2.0. How to check the correct selenium version compatible with my browser.

Comment: sry.. don't know much about selenium.. verify which service is supposed to run in port 7055 and why isn't it running..

Comment: Selenium version: 2.52.0 Firefox version: 45.2.0 It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution. Version compatible issue.
Solved by changing the combination of selenium and firefox. Selenium version: 2.52.0 Firefox version: 45.2.0 It works for me.